# Tidal current energy chart - Messina Strait

Tags: waves, mediterranean, energy

I am a student in industrial engineering, and I am doing a business plan related to exploiting Messina Strait current for electrical energy.
Does anyone have a tidal stream chart (either with velocity or energy), that I could use? Thank you to everyone

Comment: you can take a look here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289932977_Tidal_Currents_and_Transient_Phenomena_in_the_Strait_of_Messina_a_Review